# C Programming on Xcode - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, exc-bad-access

I'm current coding a C program to create, view and update employee records in a file. There's no serious errors with my program and everything compiled smoothly until I entered the employee id, Xcode would give a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I referred back to my code and this occurs at the part where it's supposed to write the data into the file (refer to comment), but I'm still not sure what went wrong here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define size 300

struct emp
{
    int id;
    char *name;
}*emp1, *emp3;

void display();
void create();
void update();

FILE *fp, *fp1;
int count = 0;

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, n, ch;

    printf("1] Create a Record\n");
    printf("2] Display Records\n");
    printf("3] Update Records\n");
    printf("4] Exit");
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter your choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 1:
                fp = fopen(argv[1], "a");
                create();
                break;
            case 2:
                fp1 = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
                display();
                break;
            case 3:
                fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
                update();
                break;
            case 4:
                exit(0);
        }
    }
}

/* To create an employee record */
void create()
{
    int i;
    char *p;

    emp1 = (struct emp *)malloc(sizeof(struct emp));
    emp1->name = (char *)malloc((size)*(sizeof(char)));
    printf("Enter name of employee : ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", emp1->name);
    printf("Enter emp id : ");
    scanf(" %d", &emp1->id);
    fwrite(&emp1->id, sizeof(emp1->id), 1, fp); //The error occurs here
    fwrite(emp1->name, size, 1, fp);
    count++;   // count to number of entries of records
    fclose(fp);
}

/* Display the records in the file */
void display()
{
    emp3=(struct emp *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct emp));
    emp3->name=(char *)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    int i = 1;

    if (fp1 == NULL)
        printf("\nFile not opened for reading");
    while (i <= count)
    {
        fread(&emp3->id, sizeof(emp3->id), 1, fp1);
        fread(emp3->name, size, 1, fp1);
        printf("\n%d %s",emp3->id,emp3->name);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    free(emp3->name);
    free(emp3);
}

void update()
{
    int id, flag = 0, i = 1;
    char s[size];

    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cant be opened");
        return;
    }
    printf("Enter employee id to update : ");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    emp3 = (struct emp *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct emp));
    emp3->name=(char *)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    while(i<=count)
    {
        fread(&emp3->id, sizeof(emp3->id), 1, fp1);
        fread(emp3->name,size,1,fp1);
        if (id == emp3->id)
        {
            printf("Enter new name of emplyee to update : ");
            scanf(" %[^\n]s", s);
            fseek(fp1, -204L, SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite(&emp3->id, sizeof(emp3->id), 1, fp1);
            fwrite(s, size, 1, fp1);
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (flag != 1)
    {
        printf("No employee record found");
        flag = 0;
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    free(emp3->name);        /* to free allocated memory */
    free(emp3);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the error occurs in the first `fwrite` call?  I'm unable to reproduce your problem using GCC on Linux, but running the program under Valgrind, the *second* `fwrite`  produces a warning because it's writing the whole 300-byte buffer even though only a portion of it has actually been initialized (by the `scanf` call).  It should still be valid to write that whole buffer (even though much of it is garbage), but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Also, do you get a signal name reported along with the error, such as SIGSEGV or SIGBUS?

Comment: Probably unrelated to the problem you are seeing, but in a hosted environment (that is, what you have) _main()_ is required to return _int_ - anything else is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Wyzard I'm pretty sure it's the first fwrite call, according to what Xcode is highlighting to me. I've included a screenshot <http://s11.postimg.org/oh8ibd78i/Screen_Shot_2015_03_19_at_1_54_48_AM.jpg>

Comment: @mlp Noted. I've added a return statement at the end of the function. Thanks a lot

Comment: From your screenshot:  "address=0x68".  That doesn't look like a valid address.  Check the values of `&emp1->id` and `fp` to see if they're sane.

Comment: @Wyzard I've just checked, emp1 is displaying 0x100200000 but fp is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that `fp` is NULL.  That means you don't actually have an open file to write to; the earlier `fopen` call returned NULL to indicate an error.  The *direct* cause of the crash is `fwrite` dereferencing a null pointer by trying to access fields of the `FILE` structure it's supposed to point to; the *indirect* cause is that you didn't check the return value from `fopen` before using it.

After each of your `fopen` calls, add something like this:

```
if (fp == NULL)
{
  perror("Failed to open file");
  exit(1);
}
```

When `fopen` fails, it returns NULL and sets the global variable `errno` to indicate what went wrong.  The `perror` function prints a descriptive message corresponding to the `errno` value.

---

Since your program expects to be given a filename on the command line (i.e. in `argv[1]`, make sure Xcode is actually giving it one.  Launching a program from an IDE typically runs it without any command-line arguments by default.  Accessing `argv[1]` when `argc` is less than 2 would be another error, and would be likely to appear as a garbage string that's not a valid filename, leading `fopen` to fail.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the if statement after the first fopen call, the output is:
Failed to open file: Bad address

Comment: On my Linux system, the manpage for errno(3) indicates that "bad address" is the message for the EFAULT error, and fopen(3) says it can produce any of the errors from open(2), and open(2) says that it produces EFAULT if the "pathname points outside your accessible address space".  [This post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/fopen-returns-with-errno-14-bad-address-4175479196/) indicates that it's likely a problem with the path string.  Most likely, Xcode didn't pass the program a filename argument so `argv[1]` is NULL.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm now trying to find out how to make sure Xcode correctly passed the filename on to fp. This program is supposed to run on Linux (my school lab is using Linux) so I believe everything would be fine there, but still I would want to solve this problem on OSX.

Comment: I've tried running my code on a Linux machine and it gave the same error.

Comment: Did you give it a filename argument when you ran it on Linux?  It won't work without one, on *any* platform.  The program stores records in a file, and it expects `argv[1]` to provide the name of that file.

Comment: How do I give it a filename argument? Isn't fp and fp1 the filename? Sorry I'm a bit new to C. BTW I've tried changing to argv[2] and it successfully opened and wrote to the file, but now it's giving me another problem when viewing from it... that's another issue which I will open a new thread if I can't come out with a solution soon.

Comment: It's not something *in* your program, it's how you run it. You have to type a filename on the command line after the name of the program. That's how you tell the program what file to save the data in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, never knew it was just that simple. My program is running fine now. Thanks for all the guidance.